# Apply XSLT to merge two XML files and copy a node when there is no key match

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XML and XSLT. What I am trying to do is merge two XML files with a key match in both files, for my case `id`. When there is a key match I copy contents of a node, for my case all the `appointment`, which works. What I want to achieve is that when there is no key match in the second file. Copy the entire missing parent node to first file, which is the `person-data`. The way I have my XSLT applied is able to copy the nodes in my first file but not copying the no key match `person-data` into the merged file. I am using XSLT version 1.0

This is my file1.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>        
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
    <appointments>
      <appointment>
        <code>1</code>
        <pass>1</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
      <appointment>
        <code>2</code>
        <pass>2</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>67890</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>5</code>
        <pass>5</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>678678</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>15</code>
        <pass>15</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>679679</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>       
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>20</code>
        <pass>20</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

This is my file2.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>        
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>  
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>     
    <appointments>
      <appointment>
        <code>3</code>
        <pass>3</pass>
        <states>
            <state>IL</state>
            <state>IN</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
      <appointment>
        <code>4</code>
        <pass>4</pass>
        <states>
            <state>NV</state>
            <state>CA</state>
        </states>
     </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>67890</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>6</code>
        <pass>6</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>141414</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>25</code>
        <pass>25</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>151515</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>30</code>
        <pass>30</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-document" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="pdata" match="person-data" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="appointments">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments/appointment"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I am getting as my result, its missing the no key match nodes in file2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>1</code>
            <pass>1</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>2</code>
            <pass>2</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>3</code>
            <pass>3</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>4</code>
            <pass>4</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>67890</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>5</code>
            <pass>5</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>6</code>
            <pass>6</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>678678</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>15</code>
            <pass>15</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>679679</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>20</code>
            <pass>20</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

This is what I actually want as my result of merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-appointment-data>
<person-data>
    <id>12345</id>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>1</code>
            <pass>1</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>2</code>
            <pass>2</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>3</code>
            <pass>3</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>4</code>
            <pass>4</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>67890</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>5</code>
            <pass>5</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
        <appointment>
            <code>6</code>
            <pass>6</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>678678</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>15</code>
            <pass>15</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>
    <id>679679</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>20</code>
            <pass>20</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>141414</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>25</code>
        <pass>25</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
<id>151515</id>
<first-name>Mike</first-name>    
<last-name>Hewitt</last-name>   
<appointments>
    <appointment>
        <code>30</code>
        <pass>30</pass>
        <states>
            <state>AK</state>
            <state>MA</state>
        </states>
    </appointment>
</appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

Can someone guide me how to update this information using this XSLT.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is that when there is no key match in the
>   second file. Copy the entire missing parent node to first file, which
>   is the person-data.

Try adding the following template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/people-appointment-data">
    <xsl:variable name="ids" select="person-data/id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup-document/people-appointment-data/person-data[not(id=$ids)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding on this.